# Memory uses continuously increasing with large size of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management

I have two large size images in the my view controller. The size of images are approximately 1500 x 1800. When I load that view controller a few times I am getting a memory warning and finally my app crashes. I did observe some memory uses. When I load the view controller my memory use is increased by 15 Mbs each time. I have read about image caching, so to avoid image caching I am not loading image from controller, instead I am loading image in the following way :

```
  UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathForImageFile1];
  imageView.image = image;
  image = nil;
```

I have declared image view inside .h file like :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

By the documentation, If I use load image with **initWithContentsOfFile** method then image should not be cached and memory should be released once unloading of view happens.

Further I tried to nil image :

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  imageView = nil;
}
```

But there is no difference in memory usage. How can I release the memory used by imageview?

Comment: where exactly do you init your image in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Reduce the size of the image programatically then load, you are using a very huge image, thats not required to show for sure your imageview is small, read the large file when needed, create a smaller version of image for use.

Comment: I think you need to resize the image view.

Comment: yes , i am loading it in ViewDidLoad , I actually need to resolve this issue without reducing size of the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `imageView` `IBOutlet` to `nil` will not unload your `imageView` because `strong` reference still remains in `imageView`'s `superview` (`subviews` array).

Unload image using:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: Setting a weak property to nil _cannot ever_ reduce memory usage. If a weak property isn't nil, there _must_ be a strong reference somewhere.

Comment: `image` is a strong property in `UIImageView`, and it will be in memory until `UIImageView` is deallocated.